# Installing a smart thermometer (ecobee4) can I move the wires around on the HVAC?

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire

I want to install an ecobee4. I want to install it with the C wire so I do not need to use their kit. It seems to me that I should be able to just move the wires around on my hvac.

Here is a diagram of my thermostat and HVAC. [image]
On the thermostat, the blue wire is just hanging out there.

Here is a page from the ecobee4 manual:

[image]

I want to make the left picture, Guide 1, work. Can I just move the wires around on my HVAC accordingly? Basically take the Blue off of the G post and put it on C.

Also, there is skinny red and white wire on the HVAC, I do not know where they go. Can I just leave them on the posts as-is or are they thermostat specific?

Here is one more pic just bc

[image]

More pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other devices on this system? A/C or humidifier...etc. You need to figure out what the wires go to first. Do you have a wire diagram for the furnace?

Comment: I will get a wire diagram this evening. And we have AC on this system. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

### Go ahead

You can take the blue wire from G and move it over to C on the furnace -- there is room for two wires on the typical furnace-board terminal.  The skinny red and white cable carries the Y and C wires to the compressor contactor on your AC's outdoor unit, by the way, and simply stays put when you do this.

Comment: That appears to have worked. I can’t test the AC because my house is too cold, but come summer I might revive this question.